# Why do 2 col-md-2 wrap although form-row is inside col-md-6?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

For some strange reason my inline form groups wrap, although their total column width is smaller than the hosting one and also on the screen it shows loads of estate for the wrapped content.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form id="pricing">    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <label for="fromDate">arrival</label>
                    <input id="fromDate" class="form-control" type="text" name="fromDate">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <label for="toDate">departure</label>
                    <input id="toDate" class="form-control" type="text" name="toDate">
                </div>
            </div>
           

            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="appartement">select appartement </label>
                    <div class="btn_group btn-group-sm" name="appartement" id="appartement" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
                          <input type="radio" class="btn-check form-control-sm" name="btnradio" id="btnradio1" autocomplete="off">
                          <label class="btn btn-outline-primary " for="btnradio1">both</label>
                        
                          <input type="radio" class="btn-check form-control-sm" name="btnradio" id="btnradio2" autocomplete="off">
                          <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio2">upper</label>
                        
                          <input type="radio" class="btn-check form-control-sm" name="btnradio" id="btnradio3" autocomplete="off">
                          <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio3">lower</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="notes" name="notes" placeholder="Notes"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>    
    <div class="row">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </div>    
</form>
```

So departure is below arrival, though 2 + 2 < 6

Also only 2 radio buttons are inline, the 3rd is in a new row

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  On Chrome for Mac, the arrival and departure fields are side-by-side, and the both/lower/upper radio buttons are also side-by-side.

Comment: I am using Safari. Initially they were side-by-side, then I changed something (to the better and actually a few things, so not sure what caused it) and now they ain't... Thanks for your effort, anyways, and good to know that it works on Chrome